# How to reliably terminate a process started via asyncssh?

Tags: python, ssh, multiprocessing, asyncssh

I have the following snippet starting a long-going process locally via ssh:

```py
from asyncio import gather, run
import asyncssh

async def listen(stream):
    async for line in stream:
        print(line)

async def main():
    async with asyncssh.connect("localhost", username="root") as conn:
        process = await conn.create_process("while true; do date; sleep 1; done")
        await gather(
            listen(process.stdout),
            listen(process.stderr),
            process.wait(),
        )
            
run(main())
```

Works fine for me (you have to be able to connect via `ssh` locally to run the snippet, of course), except I don't know how to make sure the process gets terminated when the parent process terminates.

My first idea was to `terminate()`/`kill()` the process in a `finally` block around `gather`.
This works when the parent process got a signal it can handle, e.g `SIGINT`. But in case it's been executed within an IDE/debugger or it receives `SIGSEGV` the child process will stay.

Is there a way to couple the spawned process or ssh connection with the parent process in order avoid stray processes?