# How to kill a command started via asyncssh as root?

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, asyncssh

I'm struggling with `asyncssh` again trying to kill a process started as root:

```py
import asyncio
import asyncssh

async def main() -> None:
    async with asyncssh.connect("localhost", username="root", request_pty="force") as conn:
        print("start process, now try to terminate it by pressing CTRL-C")
        async with conn.create_process("sleep 20") as process:
            await process.wait()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Running `watch -n 1 pgrep -a sleep` in another terminal and starting the script above you should see an instance of `sleep` being spawned.

Unfortunately if you try to terminate this process by terminating the script it will hang on first try and raise the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception next time, but `sleep` won't stop.

Running this script as normal user (by just omitting `username="root"`) everything works fine, so it shouldn't be an issue with signal forwarding..

Running `ssh root@localhost -t sleep 20` directly also works fine, so trying to terminate a process spawned by `root` also should be no problem.

So what's going on? How can I spawn and kill a process as `root` with `asyncssh`?

---

Note: I've posted a [quite similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100252/how-to-reliably-terminate-a-process-started-via-asyncssh) a while ago but in this case I had other tasks running in the background, so it's still a different topic